# Will ferrite rings around a metal pole hide it in an RF sense from my vertical 10 m Yagi?

Tags: antenna-theory, antenna-construction

If i mount my vertical 10 m 4 element yagi directly on a metal pole so that the pole is between the elements and so messes up the radiation pattern and input impedance, if i put lots of type 43 material ferrite rings around the pole will that 'hide' the pole from the antenna in an RF sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

W8JI's article on [*Detuning Towers*](https://www.w8ji.com/detuning_towers.htm) shows how to add a resonated loop to a conductive structure in order to make it "vanish" electrically:

[image]

When the capacitor is tuned to resonate at the frequency of interest, the loop comprising sections A and B carries *maximum* current, analogous to a tank circuit. Because the currents in A and B are equal but flow in opposite directions, the radiation from the two sections cancels. And, just like a tank circuit, the resonated A-B loop acts as a high impedance that breaks up the continuous conductor comprising sections C, A and D into smaller conductors section C and section D. By properly positioning, sizing and tuning the loop, you can use your vertically-oriented antenna on a conductive vertical support.

Answer (score 1):

For the whole pole they will be too heavy.

I made lots of LPDAs with feed cables in the middle. They had about 50 beads on the cables, each of them about 35x30 mm, with a 12 mm hole. This sort of bead has about 100 Ohm impedance, at HF you might get a bit more and so need fewer beads.
For a 50 mm pipe an equivalent bead would have a 120 mm OD, 150 mm long, and weigh several kg. You would need many of them.

Comment: But ignoring the weight would it work ?

Comment: Yes certainly. Big cores like that won't be cheap either. You would be a lot better off using smaller ferries on the legs of a lattice structure, rather than a solid pole. But the best, cheapest, lightest, is to use a fibreglass pipe and beads on the coax only.